# Downloading file open a new tab but tab stays open Safari browser

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, download

I am trying to download file using javascript `window.open()` on wordpress website. It works fine in all browser but in safari, tab stays open. It should close the tab automatically once file get downloaded. I am checking in safari version 13.1.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 window.open('admin.php?action=downloadfile&name=53t52jd6772', "_blank");
```

In `action=downloadfile` I have written code to download file in php using php `header()`. I tried to close tab forcefully using `window.close();` but in case when a confirm prompt appears to allow or cancel download then `window.close();` closes the tab without allowing user to choose action.

Is that possible to automatically close browser after file download starts? I have been looking for the solution but didn't found any working solution.